# draw circle and fill color in android without using canvas

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas, android-drawable

I am using Android Studio 2.1.2 for creating android applications. In my application, I need to create a circle filled with red color in android view. I tried it by using a canvas like,

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            int x = getWidth();
            int y = getHeight();
            int radius = x / 2;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
            canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);
        }
```

And in `onCreate()`, I have added,

```
setContentView(new SampleView(this));
```

Where `SampleView` is a class which contains `onDraw()`. Is there any alternative way to do the same thing, without using the `canvas`?

Comment: no, anything related to drawing has to be done by a `Canvas` calls, but you dont have to create a custom `View` for it to work: create a custom `Drawable` and set it to any `View` by calling `setBackground`

Comment: @pskink : After calling, `setContentView(new SampleView(this));` , the components (Buttons and TextView) which i have already in my MainActivity is hidden. Can i display the MainActivity components along with this canvas which is created to draw the circle?

Comment: yes, i already said so: `but you dont have to create a custom View for it to work [...]`, the easiest is to use a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape` class

Comment: @pskink : Thanks for your help. Let me try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a shape xml and assign it to linear layout

Some thing like this

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:background="@drawable/circle_border"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

   </LinearLayout>



<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="false">
         <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/red" />
         </shape>
     </item>
</selector>
```

this will draw a circle

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake. After clean and build, its working fine. Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create **custom_circle.xml** in `drawable`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@color/red" />

</shape>
```

Then you can use it in layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="20sp"
    android:layout_height="20sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_circle"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Yeah you can take button as well as layout too.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Create a drawable from xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
</shape>
```

You can also set size, and stroke in this drawable if you want to. Then add an `ImageView` (or whatever you want) to your layout and set the drawable to it:

```
<ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable" \>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.